# Promise/catch didn't catch promise.reject

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, tedious

My async function returns `Promise.reject`, but caller can't catch it.
I'm using Tedious and Express.
What did I mistake?

```
const connection = require('tedious').Connection;
const Request = require('tedious').Request;
const TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

async function doInsertDansok() {

  connection.on('connect', (err)=> {
      if (err) {
        log.error('connection error:', err);
        return new Promise.reject(err);
      } else {
        log.info('connection success');
        let request = new Request('SP_TEST_OUTPUT_PARAM 1, @o_retKey OUT, @o_errMsg OUT, @o_retReceiptInfo OUT', 
          (err, rowCount, rows)=> {
          if (err) {
            log.error('request error:', err);  //<== this log is written.
            return new Promise.reject(err);
          } else {
            log.info(rowCount + " rows(s) returned");
          }
        });
        request.addOutputParameter('o_retKey', TYPES.Int);
        request.addOutputParameter('o_errMsg', TYPES.VarChar, {length:100});
        request.addOutputParameter('o_retReceiptInfo', TYPES.VarChar, {length:255});
        request.on('returnValue', (parameterName, value, metadata) => {
          log.info(parameterName + ' = ' + value);
          return new Promise.resolve(parameterName, value);
        });
        connection.callProcedure(request);
      }
  })
}

exports.insertDansok = function (req, res) {
  doInsertDansok()
  .then((paramter, value)=> {
    log.info('doInsertDansok success');
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'insertdansok success.' });
  })
  .catch((e)=> {
    log.error('insertDansok Failed', e);  //<== I thought this log be written.  But not.
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'insertdansok failed.' });
  });
```

I did wrong SQL statement by `Request`.
My expectation was that `.catch((e)=>` catch `doInsertDansok` function's reject.  But didn't.

Comment: `doInsertDansok` returns nothing.

Comment: Your async function returns nothing.  You are doing `return Promise.reject(err)` from an event handler that is called sometime later so that return value just goes  back into the event system that triggered the event, not to anything you ever called.  This code is not even close to correct.  You should look up the term "promisify" if you want to see how to turn regular callbacks into promises.  The `async` keyword does not do that magically for you.

Comment: To even begin to help you, you'd have to describe how you want the `doInsertDansok()` function to work.  As it is right now, it just registers multiple event handlers and returns nothing.    If you want it to return a promise, then when exactly do you want the promise resolved and what do you want the resolved value to be?

Comment: `Promise.reject()` is not a constructor. Return it without the `new` keyword

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to promise resolve return it's rows.  I modifed my question.  Thank you.

Comment: @SrThompson `promise.reject()` without `new` was the same result.

Comment: You get `rows` from `new Request()`, but then you also have `request.on('returnValue', ...)`  What exactly is that for?  And, what does it have to do with the desired return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing with the `request.on('returnValue', ...)` part of your code, but if you just want to return a promise who's resolved value is the `rows` data, then you need to actually create a promise and return it and then `resolve()` or `reject()` it based on the outcome of your asynchronous operation like this:

```
const connection = require('tedious').Connection;
const Request = require('tedious').Request;
const TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

function doInsertDansok() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.on('connect', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                log.error('connection error:', err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                log.info('connection success');
                let request = new Request('SP_TEST_OUTPUT_PARAM 1, @o_retKey OUT, @o_errMsg OUT, @o_retReceiptInfo OUT',
                    (err, rowCount, rows) => {
                        if (err) {
                            log.error('request error:', err); //<== this log is written.
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            log.info(rowCount + " rows(s) returned");
                            resolve(rows);
                        }
                });
                request.addOutputParameter('o_retKey', TYPES.Int);
                request.addOutputParameter('o_errMsg', TYPES.VarChar, {length: 100});
                request.addOutputParameter('o_retReceiptInfo', TYPES.VarChar, {length: 255});
                request.on('returnValue', (parameterName, value, metadata) => {
                    log.info(parameterName + ' = ' + value);
                });
                connection.callProcedure(request);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer  is my expection.  I totally mis undertood async and promise.  Thank your correction.